# TinyColor isValid() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented [TinyColor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) in my project. I created an object with rgb property's and **invalid** values:

```
value = {r: 'abc', g: 'something', b: 'hello'};
```

I then created an `if-statement` checking whether it's a valid color:

```
if (tinycolor(value).isValid()) {
    console.log("Good :)");
} else {
    console.log("Wrong!!!");
}
```

No matter what values I give, I always get 'Good :)' logged. I then tried using a string instead;

```
value = 'rgb (abc, something, hello)';
```

And that gives me the correct output. If it's an invalid color, I get 'Wrong!!!', and if it's a valid color, I get 'Good :)'.

How can I check for an invalid color when using a property?

[`isValid()` documentation](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor#isvalid)

JSFiddle didn't load the file, so I had to copy/paste it.


#### JSFiddle

The code snippet isn't loading the file either. Don't know why.

```js
value = {
  r: 'abc',
  g: 'something',
  b: 'hello'
};

//value = 'rgb (abc, something, hello)';

if (tinycolor(value).isValid()) {
  console.log("Good :)");
} else {
  console.log("Wrong!!!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bgrins/TinyColor/master/tinycolor.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tinyColor rgb object conversion considers any object with the three properties r, b and g as valid input. Here's the relevant bit of code -

```
if (typeof color == "object") {
    if (color.hasOwnProperty("r") && color.hasOwnProperty("g") && color.hasOwnProperty("b")) {
        rgb = rgbToRgb(color.r, color.g, color.b);
        ok = true;
        format = String(color.r).substr(-1) === "%" ? "prgb" : "rgb";
    }
```

See the check for properties and then ok = true? That ok ends up being the return of isValid.

Comment: Oh. I get it! That's a bit misleading, I think.... Anyway, is there another way of checking if the object is a valid color?

Comment: Well, it's a valid color as far as TinyColor is concerned. It seems the author wanted to support strings like "50%". If you don't care about that, you can simply add your own check that ensures typeof obj.r, b and g all return "number".

Comment: I'll also have to check if it's between 0 - 255. How can I perform those 2 checks?

Comment: Do you care about the absolute validity of the input or do you care about producing a valid color from potentially different kinds of input? TinyColor does the latter - it will try to make something out of whatever rgb values you give it. If you want to ensure it's 3 numerical values that are between 0 and 255, you'll have to do that yourself. TinyColor will turn them into floats between 0 and 1, incidentally.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now checking whether the string is a number using this: `var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;` How can I add an empty string to `regex`?

Comment: It sounds like a completely different question nor do I have any idea what your inputs are, where they come from, what you're trying to do. In fact, if anything, if you're not using TinyColor for conversion/parsing, you probably don't need it at all.